# What actions count towards Fallout 4's Pip-Boy Combat statistics?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm interested in playing through the Zero Kills challenge which The Weirdist  [proved to be possible](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcg6Kygx-MfRzt1Kf6oUZTvdocDYtQX-M) (YouTube playlist) back in December last year. Before I begin though, I'd like to know what actions count towards the Combat statistics displayed in the Pip-Boy's Data tab:

[image: Pip-Boy's Combat statistics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm self-answering this because I know of a few actions which do count. I don't believe this to be a complete list though, so I'm definitely looking for other actions which I'm missing here:

- **Doing the things on the list**
  The obvious one; killing people, animals, creatures, robots, synths, turrets and legendary enemies along with performing critical strikes, sneak attacks and backstabs will all increase their respective counter.
- **Damaging things then having them die from other causes**
  If you attack something but don't outright kill it, but then it goes on to die anyway from other causes, it will increase the relevant counter. I guess you could say that you did contribute to the thing's death though, I suppose.
- **Having your companion perform the above actions**
  If your companion outright kills things, or attacks things which die from other causes, it also increases the relevant counter.
- **Using the Turret Override Program to disarm turrets**
  Disarming turrets counts towards the Turrets Killed listing.
- **General game glitches**
  Unfortunately sometimes the game seems to increase these counters even when you've done nothing wrong. Not much can be done to avoid this other than keeping an eye on the counters and reverting to an older save if it happens.

Are there any others?

NPCs which are not your Companions who go on to kill things do *not* appear to increase any of these counters; neither do enemies which kill other enemies (even if they were ordered to do so by you).

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. You didn't say how you know any of this. Are you sure about 2nd bulletpoint concerning companions? That didn't count in New Vegas. What exactly do you mean "disarming turrets"? Deactivating them? Sabotaging them?

Comment: @DCShannon mostly from watching through The Wierdist's YouTube playlist and comments left on the videos (linked in the question).